# Re-direct Category Menu item to different URL

Tags: url, url-rewrite, menu, sub-categories, catalog-url-rewrite

I want to redirect my Menu sub item to a different URL how can I do that?
**Like Blog Menu Item to
Dropbox.com**

[image]

I want the Blog menu to be redirected to : a seperate URL to new website for example: [www.wordpress.com](http://www.wordpress.com)

The Sub category Item are not shown In front End But is present and Enabled
at back-end admin dashboard.

[image: Sub Category Items]

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: written explanation

Comment: I want if a user click on Blog then It is re directed to www.wordpress.com

Comment: @AnonymousRecord, why dont you give the bounty to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by adding a record in **URL Rewrites**

In admin goto `Marketing -> URL Rewrites`
add new URL rewrite by clicking **Add URL Rewrite**

**Create URL Rewrite** Dropdown Select **Custom**

**Store** Select your Specific store.

**Request Path** you have to add your category URL for eg. `catalog/category/view/id/3` here **3** is the Category ID

**Target Path** add **https://www.dropbox.com**

**Redirect Type** Select **Permanent (301)**

Here is the screenshot of settings.

[image]

Hope this will help you. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Let me try and I tick this answer

Comment: I have another question If you can answer that as well

Comment: Sure you can ask.. I will try to give answer

Comment: I have edited my Question Please check It

Comment: The Sub category Item are not shown In front End But is present and Enabled at back-end admin dashboard.

Comment: check Include in Menu is yes and also confirm that category are not disabled on store view level.

Comment: Yes they all are enabled in Store view in admin dashboard

Comment: Do you know the table name where It's value might be be 0

Comment: I am done with Re index and cache

Comment: if its enabled on store view level the in db value is also 1. Check your menu code if there is something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113643/discussion-between-anonymous-record-and-rakesh-varma).